# How to submit post to wordpress via php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to post in wordpress through php
i mean i need query to insert post directly to wordpress

like

```
insert into
values
("","post title","post content " , "featured image link")
```

need some phpcode which will make this kind of query work
can anybody help ??

Comment: Are you able to use the Wordpress functions? If so, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code. Change the query field as you required.

```
$insert_contact_details = $wpdb->get_results("insert into wp_contact(first_name,contact_email,subject,message)values('".addslashes($_GET['first_name'])."','".addslashes($_GET['contact_email'])."','".addslashes($_GET['subject'])."','".addslashes($_GET['message'])."')");
```